# jQuery execute when content and external content is done loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website loads from a few external sources (photos and movies in iframes, Youtube etc)

The code below is executed when my page is loaded but also if external sources are still loading.

```
$(function() {
    //some code
});
```

Which code should I use if I want a script to be executed when all the sources are loaded? (including external sources)

Comment: `onload` istead of DOM-ready.

Comment: O yes it is! Sorry, I didn't know where to search for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try pure javascript instead:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //do stuff here
};
```